# magento-2 cart page mini cart not update with custom option

Tags: magento2.2

I am using a custom extension for adding additional option in magento2 
and its showing on cart page checkout page and in admin order.
but not update mini-cart
error is :

> [2018-08-22 06:39:29] main.INFO: Broken reference: the
>   'page.top_schedule_block0' element cannot be added as child to
>   'page.top', because the latter doesn't exist [] []

[image]

Comment: no need answer i fixed this issue